# why iframe control is not loading the source page in visual force preview?

Tags: iframe, salesforce, visualforce

I am new to salesforce. I want to use iframe control in visualforce page to load some content from .net. I've used the iframe control as follows

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:iframe frameborder="true" src="http://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</apex:page>
```

but it is not loading anything in the iframe control.It is showing only white back ground an also I tried with html iframe control but I got the same response.
So can anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Use javascript console to open debugger and please post the error that you receive .

Comment: It works for me. Which browser you are using ?

Comment: @Mohith Kumar-I'm using google chrome and are you using the external website or your own visual force page.For me local visual force page is opening but I'm unable to open external website

Comment: Hi @lax_me, looks like you're already got an answer, but so you're aware there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :) As a reference there are about 4x the questions on the new stackexchange as compared to SO and a lot more active participants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be the new chrome security controls. You can't load an http page into an iframe that is on an https page.

You will either need to get an SSL certificate for your iframe page or bypass the security controls.

A small Shield should appear in the address bar that can be used to display the blocked content