# I want to embed iframe in my visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a `Visualforce page` and i want to open in in my salesforce account, I want to display it in my page while page is not public. I want to open a website page in apex:iframe which is developed in php.

`For example` this my code:

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:iframe src="http://www.examplesite.com/" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"         height="500px" width="400px"/>        
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error..?

Comment: Yes getting error, as   http not alloweds in https

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279898/why-iframe-control-is-not-loading-the-source-page-in-visual-force-preview